# Best way to Compare two Intergers from two files. C++

Tags: c++, compare

I have two text files containing 7 digit integers on separate lines and I want a program which will compare the integers from one file to the other file.

Example date being used (some 300+ separate integers)

> 1867575
>
> 1867565
>
> 1867565
>
> 1867433

Here is my code so far which opens both files saved to the desktop.

```
#include <iostream>  //I have no idea what these do...
#include <fstream>   //Will be tidying this up once it all works
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>   

using namespace std;

int main(){


    ifstream arfile;    // Declares the first text file Applicants records - AR
    ifstream qvfile;    // Declares the second text file Qualifaction records - QV
                        // Will be comparing intergers from AR list to Qv list 


        arfile.open("C:\\Users\\sagrh18\\Desktop\\ar.txt"); // Opens the AR file

        if(!arfile.is_open()){
            printf ("AR file hasn't opened\n");
            getchar();
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // Checks the file has been opened

            }else 

                {
                qvfile.open("C:\\Users\\sagrh18\\Desktop\\qv.txt"); // Opens the Input file Qv for comparrsion.

            if(!qvfile.is_open()){
                printf ("QV file hasn't opened\n");
                getchar();
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // Checks the file has been opened
                }
                printf("I have opened the QA and AR file\n");

                        //Need a loop  to comapare Ar lines to Qv lines
                        //If there is a match do nothing
                        //If there not a match then print off the number

         }

    printf ("Program has finsihed press Enter \n");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I know what the steps are I'm just not sure how best to implement them, would using two arrays be best? What is the simplest way to read line by line as well? It's been a few years since I coded anything so any suggests would be great.

Comment: What kind of output are you planning to get at the end? Do positions of the integers matter?

Comment: Do you need to use the contents of the files once you're done with your comparison? Will each integer in one file be compared to *all* integers of the other file, or only one of the integers from the other file? Will it be a line-by-line comparison of the integers, of comparison of specific integers in the different files?

Comment: without further explanation what you mean with "best", anything that works for your is the best solution.

Comment: I won't be changing the files, I just need a list output onto the screen saying which integers appears in AR file but not in QV file.

Comment: As for best I mean just the simplest, and the input integers won't change from the example above.

Comment: "input integers won't change from the example above" ?? then why do you need to read them from a file?

Answer (score 1):

Given valid `ifstream arfile` and `ifstream qvfile` you can use an [`istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to populate `vectors`:

```
const vector<int> arvec { istream_iterator<int>(arfile), istream_iterator<int>() };
vector<int> qvvec { istream_iterator<int>(qvfile), istream_iterator<int>() };
```

Having read in the contents of both files you'll now need to compare the files the quickest way to do this is to sort `qvvec` and then use [`binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search):

```
sort(begin(qvvec), end(qvvec));

for(const auto& i : arvec) {
    if(!binary_search(cbegin(qvvec), cend(qvvec), i)) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```